# Connect glass tubes to a graham condenser

Tags: home-experiment, equipment

I am currently making a syphon coffee maker such as this one:

[image]

However, I find that all the silicon tubing used on this image between the condenser and the boiling flask / between the condenser and the Buchner funnel kind of ugly. I thought this could be solved by using a condenser (a Graham Condenser specifically for my use) with ground joints (24/40 to be precise). I found this one:

[image]

But the point of the syphon coffee maker is having a tube coming from the condenser to the bottom of the flask, the water being supposed to go up that glass tube. I therefore wonder if it is possible to attach a tube to the bottom of the Graham Condenser, going down the flask, to replicate the image.

Same thing for the top of the Graham Condenser, I would like a glass tube to be connected to the Buchner funnel.

Sorry if the information provided is not precise enough, please feel free to ask for some more details.

Comment: You're not going to get a siphon from this setup. Have a look [here](https://makezine.com/projects/build-a-behemoth-cold-brew-coffee-drip-tower/) for a pretty cool example of what you are building, which is a drip-type rig.